# No funciona swagger al publicar api en azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure, swagger

Tengo un inconveniente con swagger al parecer no incluye el archivo xml de la api al publicarse. Tengo una WebApi2 y al publicar el proyecto en azure la api se abre correctamente pero al intentar ingresar en swagger me muestra el siguiente error:

> 500 : {"Message":"An error has occurred."}
> https://api.azurewebsites.net/swagger/docs/v1

El archivo xml se encuentra en la carpeta bin y para ello en las propiedades de la api agregué la siguiente configuración dentro de compilación:

[image: compi]

Y el archivo de configuración de swagger lo tengo dentro de la carpeta App_Start, ahí tengo el método para obtener el path de la siguiente manera:

```
private static string GetXmlCommentsPath()
{
   return Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath,"bin","api.xml");
}
```

Sólo cuando hago la publicación de la api, swagger no funciona. Pero al compilar en localhost si funciona.

Comment: Deberiamos ver como esta el codigo de swagger.. pero lo mas probable es que logicamente no este disponible en produccion... porque si no, estas dejando libre tu API a todo el mundo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si en localhost te funciona, probablemente te estás olvidando de añadir en la configuración de lanzamiento **`release`** el archivo xml. Cuando ingresas en las propiedades de la api debes tener en cuenta no solo el **`debug`** si no también el **`release`** cuando vas a publicar la api en azure.

[image: release]